# What's the proper way to declare a field holding a function in dart?

Tags: class, functional-programming, dart

Imagine a silly class like this:

```dart
class ConditionalWorker{

var validityChecker= (inputs)=>true;

ConditionalWorker(this.validityChecker)

...
```

Now my question is, what is the proper way of declaring the validityChecker field?

[This tutorial](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/idiomatic-dart/#function-types-and-aliases) suggests using `typedefs`. But that's not very practical. Firstly it's a chore to write a lot of typedefs that would only be used once. And secondly these typedefs show up and pollute the autocompletion of my IDE.

The `var` works best, with custom setters/constructor arguments to keep it always of a specific kind, but I know  it's [discouraged](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/style-guide/) by the style guide.

I could do `Function<bool>` but that just a more glorified var and the amount of work is the same.

It's a shame because it's perfectly legal to have a function like this:

```dart
 bool every(bool test(E element));
```

where the parameter is a very well defined function, but I can't have a field declared the same way:

```dart
bool test(E element);
```

But hopefully there is something just as good that I didn't figure out. Right?d

Comment: Btw - the reason you can't have a field defined as: "bool every(bool test(E element));" is because this syntax collides with an abstract method definition. This is one of the downsides of the language decision to put the type before the field name. If I was the language tsar the type would be after the field name, as in Go and Scala. However Dart's goal is to be familiar, so the designers used the same syntax as C/C++/Java/C#, which leads to this unfortunate compromise.

Comment: I was actually just thinking of go when writing this question, precisely for the reason you mention. I wonder if you could solve this problem with a keyword when defining fields, like "newkeyword bool every(bool test(E element));". I suppose it's ugly, but it's a lot less typing than typedefs. Oh well.

Comment: Actually come to think of it it's only the setter that conflicts, so you can also do this ugly trick. class Foo<E> {
  Function _test;
  bool test(E element) => _test(element);
  void setTest(bool test(E element)) { _test = test; }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Function<bool>` is not specific enough (you also want to specify the number and type of the arguments you have to use typedefs. There are no other ways.

I'm not sure why you think it is not practical. If you want to specify the type for a field that references a value you have to use one of the existing classes or create a new one. It's the same for fields referencing functions.

Comment: my code is piling up an enormous amount of useless typedefs. bool(),double(),double(double),bool(bool),bool(double) and so on. Often the name of the typedef is not enough so I have to spend time tracking down the definition to figure out how it works. And then I have to dodge all those typedefs in the autocompletion tooltip. Even Java which came really late to the functional world has Function<y,x> to remove this kind of grunt work. Dart has this cool way of typing functional arguments but I can't use for declaring fields which is very annoying.

Comment: You can create a feature request at http://dartbug.com/new. I wonder why you need so many typedefs. Maybe something with the naming is wrong. (This is just an heuristic I use - if it is hard to find a good distinctive name it might indicate that I didn't fully understand the purpose or concept I try to name).

Comment: oh I agree, I am really bad at giving names.

Comment: I think this is one of the hardest, most important and most underestimated topics in programming. You're not alone ;-)

Answer (score 5):

If you want a function type more specific than `Function`, you need a `typedef`.

If you don't like to have named typedefs for every return type, you can define *generic* function types yourself.

```dart
typedef R function0<R>();
typedef R function1<S,R>(S arg1);
typedef R function2<S,T,R>(S arg1. T arg2);
typedef R function3<S,T,U,R>(S arg1, T arg2, U arg3);
```

Then you can write:

```dart
function1<int,int> curryAdd(int x) => (int y) => x + y;
```

Or if `function0` looks bad to you, you can name them `NullaryFunction`, `UnaryFuncytion`, `BinaryFunction`, `TernaryFunction`, or any other name that you like.

Answer (score 1):

With Dart 2 we can use [inline function types](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#prefer-inline-function-types-over-typedefs) and we need to use it instead of typedefs where possible.

With inline function types we now can define a function as a field or a property as simple as this:

```
final bool Function(E) test;
```